Maximal subfield of division ring
I see some book says if $D$ is a division ring, $K$ is the maximal subfield of $D$, then $K=C_{D}(K),$ where $C_{D}K:=${$d\in D|dk=kd,\forall k\in K$}. But if division ring $D$ is given then how to find the maximal subfield.
More precisely, my question is to prove if $D$ is a division ring, then $D$ contains a maximal subfield.
(A subfield $F$ of $D$ is said to be a ''maximal subfield'' if it is not properly contained in any other subfield of $D$.)

Zorn's Lemma will prove the existence, since $D$ contains at least the fraction field of the subring generated by $1$.

@ArturoMagidin Perhaps even easier, the center is a subfield.
